# Space(n) and Space(n^2) implications

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity

I've a problem where I have to prove the following statements:

(i) if $SPACE(n) \subseteq P \implies SPACE(n^2) \subseteq P$

(ii) if $P = SPACE(n) \implies SPACE(n) = SPACE(n^2)$

For the Space Hierarchy Theorems we have that $\forall f(n) = o(g(n)) \implies SPACE(g(n)) \nsubseteq SPACE(f(n))$

Using this result and the statements (i) and (ii) I have to prove that (iii) $P \neq SPACE(n)$.

I'm using the following post as reference: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40770/how-do-we-know-that-p-linspace-without-knowing-if-one-is-a-subset-of-the-othe/333956#333956

I suppose that I can use Thomas Klimpel's proof in the abovementioned link to prove the statement (i).
But how can I prove the statements (ii) and (iii)?

Accept my apologies for this question, but I'm a rookie in Theory of Complexity :)

Comment: Once you've established (i), (ii) is pretty basic. Just consider the two inclusions you need to prove (one is trivial, and the other is simply the premise of the implication).

Comment: Also, which is statement (iii)?

Comment: Thank you for your response dkaeae. (iii) is $P \ne SPACE(n)$

Comment: OK, so (iii) is pretty much establishing a contradiction between (ii) and the hierarchy theorem. Can you take it from here?

Comment: space heirachy thm already states $SPACE(n)\neq SPACE(n^2)$. Therefore $P\neq SPACE(n)$ simply by contrapositive argument.

Comment: Understood, yes dkaeae I can use the space hierarchy theorem to create the contradiction. I'll read the theorem better. Thank you very much for your answers dkaeae and Tylor Huang.